# Hover element 2 classes and effect same child

Tags: css, class, hover

Sorry if this has been asked however I cannot find the solution for multi classes to effect the same child (as they have the same child)

```
.t_main:hover, .t_half:hover .t_back {
filter: blur(0px);
```

}

However this only works for the second class '.t_half:hover'

This might be a supid question however I really am in a state where I can't figure it out.

Thank you!

Comment: just add `.t_back` on the first :hover selector ... the comma works to chain as separated selectors not adding for the prevs